# Why we transfer seried objects to the function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have read the doucument and the link is here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html .it say that

> Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is
> either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the DataFrame’s columns
> (axis=1).

Its code is here `DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, raw=False, result_type=None, args=(), **kwds)`
what  confused me is what objects passed to the function? Is the "axis=0" as the object? Why we transfer seried objects to the function?

Comment: *You* don't pass anything to `func`, `DataFrame.apply` *does that*. And it is telling you what it does.

Comment: but DYZ say that " Each column is sequentially passed to func as a pd.Series" DataFrame.apply do,what

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. What I said agrees with what DYZ said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `df.apply(func,axis=0)`, the function `func` is applied to each column of `df`, as if you executed a loop through all columns. Each column is sequentially passed to `func` as a pd.Series, and the results are collected into a new pd.DataFrame. In other words, `DataFrame.apply(func,axis=0)` is loosely equivalent to:

```
pd.concat([func(column) for column in df])
```

The same goes for rows if `axis=1`.

Comment: Does that means the each colum pass the func is tread as the object ?

Comment: In Python, everything is an object.

Comment: @DYZ true, although, I think the OP is asking "is each column the object being referred to in the apply documentation"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hard to tell what the OP is asking. Perhaps you are right.